# In a web api odata controller how to I protect some fields from being update by clients?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to get my head around web api odata controllers.

How do I modify my controller so that data can be:

1. updated by the client when they submit a form
2. left unchanged (data does not need updating)
3. updated using a server side value (client should not be able to edit this value)
4. only updated if their security level allows it

My view model:

```
    public class Order
{
    [Key]
    // left unchanged
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    // updated by the client when they submit a form
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    // updated by the client when they submit a form
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    // only updated if their security level allows it (left unchanged or may be updated by the client)
    public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    // updated by the client when they submit a form
    public string OrderNotes { get; set; }
    // updated by the client when they submit a form
    public string PrivateNotes { get; set; }
    // updated using a server side value 
    public double OrderTotal { get; set; }
    // updated using a server side value 
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    // left unchanged
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    // updated using a server side value 
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    // updated using a server side value 
    public int? Active { get; set; }
    // updated by the client when they submit a form
    public int? CreditorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Creditor Creditor { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    // PATCH: odata/Orders(5)
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Order> patch)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Order order = await db.Orders.FindAsync(key);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Patch(order);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!OrderExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(order);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not certain it works on web api as I only used it on normal MVC but create your one class derived from  : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter and implement protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) and public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext) other functions can be left empty

Comment: There is an middle tire for Web API OData in preview version now. You can get more detailed introduction on https://github.com/OData/DomainFramework/wiki/Northwind-Sample---Part-1 and https://github.com/OData/DomainFramework/wiki/Northwind-Sample---Part-2 . Please be noted this is still in preview and means no product quality guaranteed. But we'd like you to have a try and provide feedback directly on Issues on the github page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute and you can decorate the fields with that.
See [this StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27061510/3581643)