# Prevent certain fields from being overwritten with PATCH in .NET Azure Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an Azure Mobile Service with a .NET backend which uses a TableController (subclass of ApiController) to handle REST requests.

In my PATCH method I want to restrict the set of fields that are allowed to be updated. I have an AccountController where I don't want the fields `Username` and `UserId` to be overwritten.

```
public class AccountController : TableController<Account>
{
...
// PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
   public Task<Account> PatchAccount(string id, Delta<Account> patch)
   {            
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);          
   }
...
}
```

I would like to send back a meaningful HTTP response like `403: Forbidden` or similar if a client connecting to the API tries to update the username or userId. So I need some way of either knowing the content of the Delta patch or having an auto response when the 'forbidden' fields are being updated.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there is a built-in way to do that. However, you can workaround this. Create new attribute, let's say `NonEditable`.

```
public class NonEditableAttribute: Attribute 
{
}
```

Apply this attribute to properties you don't want to be patched.

```
public class Account
{
   [NonEditable]
   public string UserName {get;set;}

   ... other properties
}
```

Write some helper method that will check if changed properties on `Delta<T>` contains any of these non editable properties.

```
public bool IsValidDelta<T>(Delta<T> delta) where T: class
{
   // list of property names that can't be patched
   var nonEditablePropertyNames = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                    let attr = p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(NonEditableAttribute))
                    where attr != null
                    select p.Name;
   // list of property names that were changed
   var changedPropertyNames = delta.GetChangedPropertyNames();

   // check if changedPropertyNames contains any of propertyNames, 
   // if yes return false, if no return true;
}
```

Now, in your ApiController, just check if `Delta<T>` contains changed properties, that are not editable

```
public class AccountController : TableController<Account>
{
...
// PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
   public Task<Account> PatchAccount(string id, Delta<Account> patch)
   {    
       if(IsValidDelta(patch))        
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);          
       else
          // forbidden...
   }
...
}
```

**Please Note:** Code is not tested, and can be better designed. This is to give you general idea - treat it as pseudo code.

Comment: This is great Michael!! Thanks!

Comment: The main point is of course to run your own validation logic before calling the `UpdateAsync` method as the response. I usually find that in many implementations like this the condition is more often based on authorization logic or logic based on the state of the resource being patched, but this is a great use of Data Annotation attributes on the model definitions.

Answer (score 1):

For those, who are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` package for PATCH operation I have adapted Michael's `IsValidDelta` method to this:

```cs
public static bool IsValidPatch<T>(this JsonPatchDocument<T> patchData) where T: class
{
    var nonPatchablePropertyNames = from np in typeof(T).GetProperties()
        let nonPatchableAttribute = np.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(NonPatchableAttribute))
        where nonPatchableAttribute is not null
        select np.Name;
        
    var changedPropertyNames = patchData.Operations.Select(o => o.path.Replace("/", "").FirstCharToUpper());
        
    return !changedPropertyNames.Intersect(nonPatchablePropertyNames).Any();
}
```

where `FirstCharToUpper` needed if you are using proper naming convention for properties:

```cs
public static string FirstCharToUpper(this string str)
{
    return char.ToUpperInvariant(str[0]) + str[1..];
}
```